# Referencing a calculated index when iterating through the list

Tags: python

I am trying to refer to a calculated index whilst iterating.

```
lowercase_letters_indexed=`[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'i'), (10, 'j'), (11, 'k'), (12, 'l'), (13, 'm'), (14, 'n'), (15, 'o'), (16, 'p'), (17, 'q'), (18, 'r'), (19, 's'), (20, 't'), (21, 'u'), (22, 'v'), (23, 'w'), (24, 'x'), (25, 'y'), (26, 'z')]`
for char in plaintext:
    #if character a grammer character or space ignore it as it is not a letter
    if char in grammer or char==" ":
        ciphertext=ciphertext+char
    elif char in lowercase_letters:
        for (index,letter) in lowercase_letters_indexed:
            if char==letter:
                index=(index + cipher_shift) % 26
                ciphertext=ciphertext + lowercase_letters_indexed[index]
                print(ciphertext)
```

Error:

> ciphertext=ciphertext + lowercase_letters_indexed[index]
>       TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

I understand that In the above example, the concatenation will not work as I am simply referencing the list of tuples, should this be a list of lists?

Comment: `index` is an `integer`

Comment: yep it is an iteger

Comment: You can't compare an int with a string. You can use `str(index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to index into the tuple to find the lower case letter:

```
ciphertext=cipher text + lowercase_letters_indexed[index][1]
```